# getiing curl error 60 when running laravel new app

Tags: composer-php

the error i am  getting

```
    Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/laravel/laravel/legacy.zip/37ab32cf760406f767f6a278748546214585c93f: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'codeload.github.com'
```

when i browse 'codeload.github.com' its saying not secure

when i run composer diagnose --vvv
i get

```
Running 2.5.4 (2023-02-15 13:10:06) with PHP 8.2.0 on Windows NT / 10.0
Loading config file C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/config.json
Loading config file C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json
Reading C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\composer.json)
Loading config file C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/config.json
Loading config file C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json
Loading config file C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\composer.json)
Loading config file C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer/auth.json
Reading C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer/auth.json (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\auth.json)
Checked CA file C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt: valid
Executing command (C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer): git branch -a --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git --version
Executing command (C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer): hg branch
Executing command (C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer): fossil branch list
Executing command (C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer): fossil tag list
Executing command (C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer): svn info --xml
Reading C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\composer.json)
Loading config file C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/config.json
Loading config file C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json
Loading config file C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\composer.json)
Loading config file C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer/auth.json
Reading C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer/auth.json (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\auth.json)
Reading C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.lock (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\composer.lock)
Reading C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/composer/installed.json (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\composer\installed.json)
Reading C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/composer/installed.json (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\composer\installed.json)
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: Executing command (CWD): git config color.ui
OK git version 2.39.2
Checking http connectivity to packagist: Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
[200] http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
[200] https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
OK
Checking github.com rate limit: Downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit
[200] https://api.github.com/rate_limit
OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: Downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions
[200] https://getcomposer.org/versions
OK
Composer version: 2.5.4
PHP version: 8.2.0
PHP binary path: C:\xampp\php\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
cURL version: 7.85.0 libz 1.2.12 ssl OpenSSL/3.0.7
zip: extension present, unzip not available, 7-Zip not available
```

i tried downloading the cacert file and adding it to

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

but im still getting the same

Comment: Sounds like you have a certificate problem. Do you use any proxy server or VPN?

Comment: no i dont use a proxy or vpn